# How to verify A100 GPU will work on existing server?

Tags: server, gpu

I was asked to verify that we can install two new NVIDIA A100 GPUs (PCIe version) on our existing servers.  Both are Supermicro multi-GPU boxes that current house 8 1080 Tis and Quadro RTX 6000's.

According to Supermicro support, our systems haven't been tested with this card, so I'm getting a vague "maybe".  At least from a power perspective we should be able to support them.

1. Are there any other system parameters (e.g. CPU, PCI bus bandwidth, DRAM speed and amount), I need to consider in order to ensure they will work?
2. What additional aspects do I need to consider for **optimal** performance?

Thanks,

Shahar

Comment: 1) Are the GPUs software compatible with the 1080 TI and/or Quadro RTX?  2)  Will just two cards work optimally, or will you need to replace all eight cards?  The only way to find out is either take one server down and test or buy a third Supermicro for testing.  Your vendor has said maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting two A100 and plugging them into the system instead of our Quadro RTX 6000's.  Verdict: they work.